# How reduce quality of output mp3 file size in ShineMP3encoder?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, flash-cs5, shinemp3encoder

I use AS3 to record and send users sound to server. I want to reduce the size of recorded file.I have used ShineMP3Encoder to convert recorded WAV to MP3. Is there a way to reduce quality of outputted MP3 file?

Answer (score 0):

you can check update over here: https://github.com/emj365/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy/commit/89bc8fe39f5bbecff745ee918095bd5c62c04eea